# Port visibility on Windows Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, windows-server-2012

I have a bundled REST API application in Net Core on Windows Server

[image]

I have unblocked the Port in Firewall 
(I added Inbound Rules with this `Port 1555`)

[image]

The application is not visible outside the server at all

Additional information:

- app locally works on `1555`
- when I connect to port `80`, the site works outside

Comment: I think this problem caused by wrong Firewall configuration. Check `Protocols and Ports` tab in rules properties again.

Comment: @MohammadShadman I checked several times. It must be something else

Comment: Did you apply this rule to **Domain**,**Private** and **Public**?

Comment: @MohammadShadman Yes, I think this is not a Firewall problem. I turned it off completely and it doesn't work either